# Excel: transform TEXT like "YYYYMMDD" to DATE

Tags: excel, date

How can I transform a column with text like "20130213" to DATE?

Basically, I need to calculate the difference in days between 2 dates that come in the text format

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use for example

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,5,2),RIGHT(A1,2))
```